# Element with highest occurence in array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I need to find the element with the highest occurrence in an array of strings. I am not sure what to do, since I don't have much experience with this. I don't know pointers / hashtables.

I've already done this for integers, but I can't make it work for strings.

My version:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,4,4,5};
    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int );
    int *b=new int [n];
    fill_n(b,n,0); // Put n times 0 in b

    int val=0; // Value that is the most frequent
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        if( ++b[a[i]] >= b[val])
            val = a[i];

    cout<<val<<endl;
    delete[] b;
    return 0;
    }
```

Any help for finding the most frequently occurring element in the array of strings is appreciated!

Comment: It could look almost the same way, but you'd been using `std::map<std::string, int>` instead of `int* b`.

Comment: Erm.. i've tried maps, didn't really make it work, I've been searching for hints on Google for an hour, didn't manage to find anything useful...

Comment: What did you try for stings?

Comment: @JohnSmith - You have given us the code for integers. So where is your code for strings?

Comment: I don't have one, because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @JohnSmith - Not made a start on it and found the bit you cannot resolve?

Comment: How do I start if I don't know how to?

Comment: @JohnSmith - The code above that you gave us?

Comment: That code works with integers only, unfortunately. I tried converting it to work with strings, couldn't do it.

Comment: @JohnSmith - So you tried - why not let us have a butchers at that?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I just wanted to find a solution of my problem asap.. will pay more attention next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) of strings and to use a [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map) to count occurrences:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  vector<string> a;
  map<string, int> m;

  // fill a with strings
  a.push_back("a");
  a.push_back("b");
  a.push_back("b");
  a.push_back("c");
  a.push_back("c");
  a.push_back("c");
  a.push_back("d");
  a.push_back("e");

  // count occurrences of every string
  for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
      map<string, int>::iterator it = m.find(a[i]);

      if (it == m.end())
        m.insert(pair<string, int>(a[i], 1));

      else
        m[a[i]] += 1;
     }

  // find the max
  map<string, int>::iterator it = m.begin();
  for (map<string, int>::iterator it2 = m.begin(); it2 != m.end(); ++it2)
    {
      if (it2 -> second > it -> second)
      it = it2;
    }

  cout << it -> first << endl;  
  return 0;
}
```

This solution is probably not the best one in terms of elegance and efficiency, however it should give the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I'll see what can I do with this. Just a quick question, why do you use the arguments "argc" in int main()?

Comment: Well, actually for nothing. I'm just used to write them, but in this case `int main(int argc, char * argv[])` can be replaced with `int main()` and the program still works.

Comment: Yes, I know that it works, but I've seen a lot of people using that and I don't know why. Anyway, I've got a minor problem, how do you manually enter the elements through cin for a vector instead of doing push_back? I've tried doing a for loop for push_back(i) but it didn't work well.

Comment: You can simply unconditionally do `++m[ a[i] ]`. Checking whether the key exists yet with `find()` is unnecessary and pessimising since the subscript operator already searches. Said operator also will create the key if it does not exist and value-initialise the value i.e. `0`, so it does the right thing in the 1st case too - starts at `0` then `++` to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

First, consider using C++ containers like vectors instead of plain arrays. (Search for "array to vector" or such to convert between them if you need.)

Then, if you can use C++11, you can do something like this (without C++11 it would become a bit more lengthy, but still doable):

```
std::string most_occurred(const std::vector<std::string> &vec) {
  std::map<std::string,unsigned long> str_map;
  for (const auto &str : vec)
    ++str_map[str];

  typedef decltype(std::pair<std::string,unsigned long>()) pair_type;

  auto comp = [](const pair_type &pair1, const pair_type &pair2) -> bool {
    return pair1.second < pair2.second; };
  return std::max_element(str_map.cbegin(), str_map.cend(), comp)->first;
}
```

---

Here is a version compatible with older C++

```
bool comp(const std::pair<std::string,unsigned long> &pair1,
          const std::pair<std::string,unsigned long> &pair2) {
  return pair1.second < pair2.second;
}

std::string most_occurred(const std::vector<std::string> &vec) {
  std::map<std::string,unsigned long> str_map;
  for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = vec.begin();
       it != vec.end(); ++it)
    ++str_map[*it];
  return std::max_element(str_map.begin(), str_map.end(), comp)->first;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using C++96 or whatever it is (the "normal" one).. I don't really know C++11, pretty much nothing about it(except that I've heard about it).

Comment: @JohnSmith All modern C++ programmers should know C++11, which is nothing but modern C++. But I have anyway posted another version compatible with older C++.

Comment: I just started a month ago, so I doubt I will get to learn C++11 any soon. Thank you for converting it though.

Comment: I understand. But keep in mind that a good modern C++ book will teach you C++11 as a part of the package. I suppose few books have yet to be updated, which is unfortunate, but one that has been is "C++ Primer" by Lippman. I've been studying C++ myself through that book :)

Comment: I'm currently reading Accelerated C++ by Andrew Koenig and Barbara E. Moo.