# how to find the maximum occurrence of a string in string array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, max, multiple-occurrence

I have a string array like

```
{"A", "B", "AA", "ABB", "B", "ABB", "B"}
```

how do I find the string ( "B" ) which occurs the largest number of times in an array like this in c++?

Thank you

Comment: how did you find out that `"B"` occurs most often in your example? Thats how you do it ;). Please show your code. No matter how broken or incomplete it helps us to help you.

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a code-writing service. Did you try anything at all yet? What specific problem(s) did you encounter?

Comment: I just made a simple array as an example.

Comment: Among possible duplicates is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055800/element-with-highest-occurence-in-array-of-strings)

Comment: @Jithin D Mathew What is the type of elements of the array? That is show how the array is declared. Are elements of the type std::string or const char *?

Comment: You could try looking at some [search algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_algorithm) to get some ideas.

Comment: Real easy.  Use `std::map<std::string, int>`.  The `std::string` is the string you read.  The `int` is the frequency.  If the string (key) is found, increment the frequency (value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If elements of the array has the type `std::string` then without using additional memory resources the function that finds the element that occurs more often in an array can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

size_t max_occurence( const std::string a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t max = 0;
    size_t max_count = 0;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i != n; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 0;
        
        while ( j != i && a[j] != a[i] ) ++j;
        
        if ( j == i )
        {
            size_t count = 1;
            while ( ++j != n )
            {
                if ( a[j] == a[i] ) ++count;
            }
            
            if ( max_count < count )
            {
                max = i;
                max_count = count;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return max;
}

int main() 
{
    std::string a[] = { "A", "B", "AA", "ABB", "B", "ABB", "B" };
    
    auto max = max_occurence( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );
    
    std::cout << "The most often encountered string is " << a[max] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The most often encountered string is B
```

An alternative approach is to write a generic template function. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

template <typename ForwardIterator, 
          typename BinaryPredicate = std::equal_to<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type>>
ForwardIterator max_occurence( ForwardIterator first, 
                               ForwardIterator last, 
                               BinaryPredicate binary_predicate = BinaryPredicate() )
{
    auto max = first;
    typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::difference_type max_count = 0;
    
    for ( auto current = first; current != last; ++current )
    {
        auto prev = first;
        
        while ( prev != current && !binary_predicate( *prev, *current ) ) ++prev;
        
        if ( prev == current )
        {
            typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::difference_type count = 1;
            
            while ( ++prev != last )
            {
                if ( binary_predicate( *prev, *current ) ) ++count;
            }
            
            if ( max_count < count )
            {
                max = current;
                max_count = count;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return max;
}


int main() 
{
    std::string a[] = { "A", "B", "AA", "ABB", "B", "ABB", "B" };
    
    auto max = max_occurence( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );
    
    std::cout << "The most often encountered string is " << *max << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
The most often encountered string is B
```

Comment: Wow.  You may want consider including an example that uses `std::map<string, int>`, where *string* is the string read and *int* is the frequency.  I believe it will be shorter than your first two examples.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews There is at least one drawback of using this approach is that you will not get an iterator to the target element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using `std::map`.

```
typedef std::map<std::string, int> Frequency_Map;
int main()
{
  const std::vector<std::string> test_data =
  {
      "A", "B", "AA", "ABB", "B", "ABB", "B",
  };

  Frequency_Map    frequency_table;
  std::string s;
  const size_t length = test_data.length();
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
  {
      Frequency_Map::iterator iter(frequency_table.find(test_data[i]);
      if (iter != frequency_table.end())
      {
          ++(iter->second);
      }
      else
      {
          frequency_table[test_data[i]] = 1;
      }
  }

  for (Frequency_Map::iterator iter = frequency_table.begin();
       iter != frequency_table.end();
       ++iter)
  {
      std::cout << iter->first << "    " << iter->second << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The code above builds a frequency table using `std::map` and then outputs the strings and their frequencies.  The above code can easily be modified to find the string that has the largest (maximum) frequency.

Comment: No need of `map::find`, `++frequency_table[test_data[i]]` wold be enough.

Comment: Typedef? map.find? No initailzed variables? No structured bindings for output? Wow.